# Factory of type

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In order to create an arithmetic evaluator, I have to create a Factory that would take a string in parameter, and return, depending on the string, a variable of a different type.

Example:

```
TypeFactory.make("int") return int i=0;
TypeFactory.make("float") return float f=0;
```

I thought of many different kind of implementation, but none seems to work:

I could make a class Type, and its children Float and Int, that would be returned by the factory, but then how could I get the value in the class in a generic way (like Type.getVal(), it wouldn't exist, so I couldn't use it in the rest of my program)

I hope I'm being clear in my question (it's not even really clear for me!)

Does anyone have some idea?
Thanks

EDIT:

As I realise that this question is hard to undestand, I will explain what I have to do in a more general way.

The goal is to evaluate arithmetic expressions from a file.
Exemple:

```
int a;
float b;
float c;
a=1;
b=6;
c=a+b;
```

that's my file.
My program will construct a Tree from those expressions. I use Composite and Visitor patterns for that. But MY problem is, I have to distinguished each types before, to tell which variable is of which type when my visitor do the operations, and be able to have a result of the proper type.

Comment: Looks like you're just looking for the `default(...)` operator.

Comment: Do you know about templates? Does the type need to be given as a string?

Comment: yes I know about templates, but I don't think this can be used here because the type would have to be defined as the declaration of the class, which we can't do. (but maybe there is another way with template that I don't see). The type need to be given as a string because the whole idea is to read it from a file.

Comment: Create a type super-class(`class type{};`) and use a `std::map<std::string, type>`

Comment: This isn't the problem, I do intend to stack the "type" in a map once they are created. What I can't do is everything else.

@Iliya Kogan I'm looking at default(), I didn't know it. Could you explain how it would help?

Comment: If the set of types is known at compile-time, check out `boost::variant`. Otherwise you have to make an abstract base class and generate `std::unique_ptr`'s to them, and define a sub class for each type you want to support.

Comment: And what would you possibly do with an object whose type you can only know at runtime?

Comment: @GManNickG problem with boost::variant or boost::any, I can't use operators +-/* on them, so I can't use them later to evaluate my expressions.

Comment: @Crumble: Right, you'd dispatch those operators at run-time based on what's being stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to parse and evaluate typed arithmetic expression.

The usual strategy (used in compilers) is to build a abstract syntax tree and then evaluate this tree.
The pattern you need is 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern.

Basically you represent your program/expression as a tree of Nodes. Node is an abstract class with many derived types that stand for each type of piece of expression.
The visitor pattern allow you to call the correct visitor, for each type of node, and thus decide of the correct code to execute.

```
struct Visitor
{
  void process(IntNode i) { int r = i.getInt(); ... }
  void process(FloatNode f) { float r = f.getFloat(); ... }
};

struct Node
{
    virtual void getProcessed(Visitor v);
};
struct IntNode : Node
{
    virtual void getProcessed(Visitor v) { v.process(*this); }
    int getInt() {...};
};
```

Comment: Actually you're completely right, this is what I do, I use Composite and Visitor pattern (and that works fine). But the issue is before that: I must be able to visit node that would have different type, like float or int...

Comment: Your abstract node must be able to answer what its dynamic type is. Once you have the type, and the correct visitor, you can call getFloatValue, or getIntValue depending of the cases. You can also simply put a `boost::any value` in your node and let the correct visitor do `get<type>(node.value);`

Comment: It might be worth extending IntNode/FloatNode to instead be a single template class, template, then instead of `void process(IntNode/FloatNode)` you just have `void process(TypeNode<int>)` and `void process(TypeNode<float>)`, makes it easier to add additional types and reduces code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try `boost::variant` if you have a finite list of possible types.

Suppose you only support `int` and `float`.  Then your data would be stored as a `boost::variant<int,float>`.

To access the values, you'd use `apply_visitor`.  Adding two values requires double-dispatch, which is tricky, but doable.  Your visitor to one then visits the other argument, and based on the two types generates a different result.